# Get notified when new post created

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I looking for a way to get notified from facebook whenever a new post has been created.
So far the only solution I've found is cron job to check every few minutes.
Don't the facebook sdk provide such method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Facebook Graph API Subscriptions

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/01/31/how-to--subscribing-to-data-changes-using-the-real-time-updates-api/

```
<?php

  $app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  $app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
  $app_url = 'http://YOURAPPURL';
  $fields = 'feed';
  $verify_token = 'YOURVERIFYTOKEN';

  // Fetching an App Token
  $app_token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
                   .$app_id.'&client_secret='.$app_secret
                   .'&grant_type=client_credentials';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $app_token_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $res = curl_exec($ch);
  parse_str($res, $token);

  if (isset($token['access_token'])) {
    // Let's register a callback
    $params = array(
      'object'
        =>  'user',
      'fields'
        =>  $fields,
      'callback_url'
        // This is the endpoint that will be called when
        // a User updates the location field
        =>  $app_url . '/index.php?action=callback',
      'verify_token'
        =>  $verify_token,
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
                                  .$app_id.'/subscriptions?access_token='
                                  .$token['access_token']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res && $res != 'null') {
      print_r($res);
    }

    // Fetch list of all callbacks
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
  }
  if ($res && $res != 'null') {
    print_r($res);
  }
  curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Some more helpful links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

Comment: The permission `user_subscriptions` you are referring to has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with real-time updates – it is to read who a user is subscribed to/who subscribed to them, in regard to the “follow” feature …